# servlet response to android device

Tags: java, android, json, servlets

I am in a ditch since last few days trying out to get this,but not able to bring out any desired results.I will try to make myself clear that what i am looking for in following points:

- I am working on android app,that will update the location of the user on the server using servlets(on my localhost).There is no problem regarding this,all is working fine.
- The real problem that came in my way was when i was trying to get response from server back to android device,i just want to return a simple string,or something like that,Most likely a parameter,that will be utilized by the android  app.Then i came to know about the json thing that i have to use it for doing what i am looking for.I have searched a lot about it,found some code too,but not able to use it well,

### So my questions are

1. Is it possible to retrieve response from the servlet,and extract the required values from it without using json or any parsing technique,because i needed something like a single string only.
2. `HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpGet request=new HttpGet();
   URI address=new URI("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/MyServlet");
   request.setUri(address);
   HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);`[image: code for the servlet is something like this]
   The code from the android device requesting the response and the servlet are shown above,however when i call the toString method on response.toString() in android device,it yield me a string with some sequence of numbers,which are of no use to me.
   HELP! HELP! HELP!

---

A simple example of it might help me up,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a servlet that generates plain text result without any encoding technique.

On the server side, just replace your doGet function to look like that:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello World");
}
```

On the client side, you could use the following code:

```
try {
    final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://SERVLET_URL/");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    Log.i(TAG, "Servlet Result: " + EntityUtils.toString(entity));
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "ClientProtocolException", e);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "ParseException", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,that helped me.... :),i was looking to start  with a simple string to pass,then to move  on other types,Thanks again.